# Can you save query while it is running?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

I am working on a very long stored proc in `SSMS`.  In addition to having the stored proc in the database I have the `ALTER PROC` statement saved to a *.sql* file.  If I run a portion of the stored proc (such as a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` statement), can I continue to make changes and save those changes to the *.sql* file while the query is running?

**NOTE**:  I am only concerned about saving to the *.sql* file, not to the DB by running an `ALTER` PROC statement.

Comment: Did you give it a try?  You would have gotten your answer 20x faster than it took to ask this question. (Spoilers: the answer is yes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, saving the .sql file only saves the script, regardless of what is running inside of it.